# writing papers: definition in word or formula?

Tags: definition, article-writing

If we write papers, is it or is it not desirable to write definitions in formulas AND words. 
So if I want to define the following set:
$$S:=\{ x \in \mathbb{N} : P(x) \}$$ where $P$ is some predicate (more concrete in the context of paper).

Should I write:

A) Let $S:=\{ x \in \mathbb{N} : P(x) \}$ denote the set of all natural numbers for which P is satisfied.

B) Define $S:=\{ x \in \mathbb{N} : P(x) \}$.

C) Let $S$ denote the set of all natural numbers for which P is satisfied.

Which is the best Version?

Comment: I would think that B) or C) is fine, but that A) is not good because it's redundant.

Comment: Writing "Define $S:=$..." is the same as writing "Define define $S=$...".

Comment: @littleO
Do you think this, even if "for which P is satisfied" is stated differently, e.g. 

Let $S:=\{x \in \mathbb{N} \ : \ f(x)=0 \}$ denote the set of all roots of $f$. 

Is this considered as redundant, too?

Comment: This question might be too opinion-based. I don't have any real preference between the three options. If the set had a more complicated definition, then I would probably be more strongly against C) and more strongly in favour of A). The aim should always be clarity, but this can be extremely subjective.

Comment: I tend to use words, then back it up with symbols. So I would go for A in reverse.

Comment: Redundancy is not necessarily a bad thing.  In fact I'm often grateful for redundant explanations in technical papers.

Comment: I vote for alternative C.

Answer (score 3):

I like to make things clear. So personally I would go for the following option.

> D) Let $S$ denote the set of all natural numbers for which $P$ is satisfied.
>   $$
> S=\{x\in \mathbb{N}:P(x)\}
> $$
>   Blah blah blah...

As this is a definition, so it is nice to be precise, clear, and to make it stand out. However, this all depends on context. For example, is it an important definition, or a minor technical one? Is the property $P$ very complicated, or simply "$x$ is even"? (I exaggerate about the simplicity, but putting the definition on its own line will perhaps allow you to write out $P$ in all its gory detail if you wish.)

Also, it is helpful to read about what others have written. People keep telling me that the Benson Farb school write beautifully (and I tend to agree with these people) so I read his (and his colleagues) papers to see how the "good people" do it. I don't really understand the maths, but seeing how they present their work is very helpful.

Finally, if the editor doesn't like it then listen to them. But this would be an obscenely harsh reason for rejecting a paper...